# Where to find Widget code in Magento

Tags: widget, rma

I want to adjust a widget and I think this is the code for it in widget.xml (below)

Is this where i can adjust/remove the title text that is placed everytime i place the widget in a block?

```
<widgets>
<sales_widget_guestfrom type="sales/widget_guest_form" translate="name description" module="sales">
    <name>Orders and Returns</name>
    <description>Orders and Returns Search Form</description>
    <is_email_compatible>1</is_email_compatible>
    <parameters>
        <title translate="label">
            <visible>0</visible>
            <label>Anchor Custom Title</label>
            <type>text</type>
        </title>
        <template>
            <required>1</required>
            <visible>1</visible>
            <label>Template</label>
            <type>select</type>
            <value>sales/widget/guest/form.phtml</value>
            <values>
                <default_template translate="label">
                    <label>Default Template</label>
                    <value>sales/widget/guest/form.phtml</value>
                </default_template>
            </values>
        </template>
    </parameters>
    <supported_blocks>
        <left_column>
            <block_name>left</block_name>
            <template>
                <default>default_template</default>
            </template>
        </left_column>
        <right_column>
            <block_name>right</block_name>
            <template>
                <default>default_template</default>
            </template>
        </right_column>
    </supported_blocks>
</sales_widget_guestfrom>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found it

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/widget/guest/form.phtml

I commented this out of the code:

```
<!--                <strong>-->
<!--                    <span>--><?php //echo $this->__('Orders and Returns') ?><!--</span>-->
<!--                </strong>-->
```

Title of the widget is now gone, which i wanted.

Does anyone know if this destroys something else or does this just remove the title?

Comment: yes, It just remove title, but for best practice you copy the  same folder structure in your  theme and then comment  it

Comment: It's not really clear for me, why should i copy the folder structure in my theme? I commented it out of the widget, if the widget is not active then it doesn't show the widget title anywhere right?

Comment: It's better not to modify your base for 2 reason. 1) If in any time you want switch back 2) If you upgrade your version then all the changes you did in base will lost.